# Warum heißt es in der Lutherbibel »antworten und sprechen«?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, history

In Luthers Bibelübersetzung sowie in der Vielzahl der Übertragungen in heutiges Deutsch kommen an vielen Stellen Formulierungen vor wie:

> Der Engel *antwortete und sprach* zu ihr […] (Lukas 1:35)

Es ist schon aus dem Kontext klar, dass nur eine gesprochene Antwort gemeint sein kann – der Engel wurde vorher angesprochen, von Papyrus oder demgleichen ist nirgendwo die Rede. Auch an anderen Stellen würde niemand vermuten, dass eine andere Form der Antwort (geschrieben, in Gesten) gemeint sei.

Heutzutage wird *antworten* in diesem Zusammenhang impliziert als *sprechen* verstanden. Der Zusatz *und sprach* wirkt befremdlich und macht wahrscheinlich einen Großteil des »Bibelklangs« aus.

Warum hat Luther damals diese Dopplung übersetzt? Liegt sie im griechisch-hebräischen Original so vor, oder war es damals üblich *antworten* (und andere Verben an anderen Stellen) nicht automatisch mit *sprechen* zu assoziieren?

Comment: Das gleiche findet sich in älteren Übersetzungen in andere Sprachen, nicht aber in moderneren Übersetzungen. Ich finde daher plausibel, dass das dicht an der griechischen Konstruktion ist. Es müsste mal jemand schauen, der das lesen kann... Zum Vergleich: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lucas+1%3A35

Comment: Wie würdest du denn "Und Gott sprach" auffassen? Ich könnte wetten, ich habe Gott noch nie reden gehört. Engel genau genommen auch nicht...

Comment: @Em1 Ohne theologisch großartig argumentieren zu wollen: Doch, als Gerede Gottes. Wer sagt dir denn, dass er zu dir schon hat reden wollen? ;) Aber zu sehr off-topic mE.

Comment: Die Frage setzt die Kenntnis des Textes im Original, mutmaßlich Griechisch, voraus. Es gibt hier irgendwo ein Forum für Bibelexegese - da könnte es auch passen. Was "antworten" und "sprechen" bedeutet ist dem Frager ja offensichtlich geläufig.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Wendung „antwortete und sprach“ hält sich eng am altgriechischen Original:

> καὶ ἀποκριθεὶς ὁ ἄγγελος εἶπεν αὐτῇ·

Dieser Satz enthält die Verbdoppelung ἀποκριθεὶς [*apokriteis*] von [ἀποκρίνω](http://biblehub.com/greek/611.htm) [*apokrino*] „antworten“ und εἶπεν von λέγω [*lego*] „sprechen“. Auch wenn die Verben (jedenfalls nach dem heutigen Sprachgefühl) praktisch synonym sind, entspricht es der philologischen Korrektheit, die Doppelung auch im Deutschen wiederzugeben.

Eine griechisch-englische Interlinearfassung findet sich bei [biblehub.com](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/1.htm).

Online gibt es auch eine [Übersicht über die Übersetzungsvarianten in den neueren deutschen Bibelübersetzungen](http://bibelwissen.bibelthemen.eu/wiki/index.php/Lk_1:35).

Noch eine letzte Ergänzung: Luther hat im Jahr 1533 eine kurze Schrift ([*„Summarien über die Psalmen und Ursachen des Dolmetschens“*](http://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/diglit/luther1665)) veröffentlicht, in der er insbesondere seine Psalmenübersetzung erläutert. Er sieht vor allem dann Begründungsbedarf, wenn er sich von der direkten, wörtlichen Übersetzung löst. Die Verbdoppelung im Beispiel kann man vielleicht noch als Glättung bezeichnen (Verbindung der beiden Verben mit "und" statt Verwendung des Partizip), aber darüber hinaus bestand wohl kein Bedürfnis danach, sich weiter vom Urtext zu entfernen.

Comment: Ist das ein „antwortete und sprach“ oder eher „antwortend sprach“?

Comment: Wenn ich es recht sehe (ich stöbere noch nach einem Beleg): „antwortend“, also Partizip.

Comment: Danke! Young's Literal Translation hat „And the messenger answering said to her“ und La Nuova Diodati „E l'angelo, rispondendo, le disse“, deshalb habe ich gefragt.

Comment: Ich habe dann für die alttestamentarischen Vorkommen der gleichen Konstruktion noch jemanden gefragt, die Hebräisch lernt, und sie hat mir bestätigt, dass es auch dort im Original (z. B. 1. Mose 3:9) zwei Verben gibt: »Und Gott, der HERR rief Adam und sagte«.

Comment: Stimmt - es gibt auch die identische Formulierung "antwortete und sprach", z.B. [Hiob 6: וַיַּעַן אִיּוֹב וַיֹּאמַר  "Hiob antwortete und sprach: ..."](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/job/6.htm)

Answer (score 5):

> Heutzutage wird antworten impliziert als sprechen verstanden.

Keineswegs, das hängt ganz vom Kontext ab. In einem Satz wie

> Ich habe ihr vorgestern eine E-Mail geschrieben und sie hat innerhalb einer Stunde geantwortet.

hat *sie* vermutlich kein Wort *laut ausgesprochen*, sondern lediglich zurückgeschrieben.

Aus dem Kontext lässt sich also schließen, auf welche Weise die Antwort erfolgt ist, weshalb oft die ausdrückliche Beschreibung, wie diese Antwort übermittelt wurde, ausgelassen wird. Dies lässt sich besonders gut beobachten, wenn die Antwortmethode von der zuvor genannten Kommunikationsmethode abweicht:

> Ich habe ihr vorgestern eine E-Mail geschrieben und sie hat innerhalb einer Stunde telefonisch geantwortet.

Meistens wird tatsächlich die Verkürzung verwendet, nur "antworten" zu sagen, aber ich denke, der "Bibelklang" kommt eher durch die Verwendung des Wortes "sprach" an Stelle von "sagte".

Comment: Das mit dem Kontext ist natürlich richtig; aber im Zusammenhang würde ich fast vermuten, dass die Kollegin biblisch gesprochen *geantwortet und geschrieben* habe … Es gäbe aber im Bibeltext an der Stelle (und an den vielen anderen) keinen Grund anzunehmen, dass die Antwort nichtsprachlich erfolgt sei, zumal auch der Vorsatz gesprochen wurde. Ich habe die Frage bearbeitet, um einzufügen, dass sich *sprechen* schon aus dem Kontext ergeben haben müsste.

Comment: @Jan: "Sie hat innerhalb einer Stunde geantwortet und geschrieben: 'Wir liefern nicht vor Mittwoch.'" klingt für mich jetzt erst mal nicht altmodischer oder uneleganter als "Sie hat innerhalb einer Stunde geantwortet: 'Wir liefern nicht vor Mittwoch.", einfach nur minimal länger.

Comment: Und nun nehmen wir noch das Präteritum mit rein: *Sie antwortete und schrieb: »Wir liefern nicht vor Mittwoch«*, und ich überlege mir schon, ob die Lieferung Manna enthält ;)